# List all blogs from users in same group

Tags: organic-groups

I'm new to Drupal, and I'm using Organic Groups to make groups. The site is supposed to be a multi-blog platform where groups can have their own group and the group admin(only) should be able to get a list of all group members (linked to their blogs) in the side menu. How am I able to achieve this? Any help would be appreciated!

I found the following code from [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/83615):

```
<?php
    $query = db_select('node', 'n');
    $query->join('users', 'u', 'n.uid = u.uid');
    $query->join('file_managed', 'f', 'f.fid = u.picture');
    $query->fields('u',array('name'));
    $query->fields('n',array('type'));
    $query->fields('f',array('filename'));
    $query->fields('u',array('uid'));
    $query->condition('u.status', 1);
    $query->condition('n.status', 1);
    $query->condition('n.type', 'blog', '=');
    $query->addExpression('COUNT(n.uid)');
    $query->groupBy('u.uid');
    $query->groupBy('n.type');
    $query->orderBy('COUNT(n.uid)', 'DESC');
    $result = $query->execute();
    $output = array();
    while($record = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
    // print $record ;
     $output = '<div class="bloglist_row">';
     $output .= '<div class="bloglist_userimage"><img style="width:100%;" src="./sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/pictures/'.$record['filename'].'"></div>';
     $output .= '<div class="bloglist_row_body"><a href="blog/'.$record['uid']. '">'.$record['name']. 's Blog</a><br />Posts: ('.$record['expression'].')</div>';
     $output .= '</div>';
     $output .= '<img src="blog_spacer.jpg" width="220" height="25" />';
   //  $output .= '<li />'.l($record['name']. ' ('.$record['expression'].')', 'blog/'.$record['uid']);
    }
    echo $output;
?>
```

Unfortunately this gives me the following error:
`Notice: Array to string conversion in include()` on the last line (`echo $output`).

Any ideas on how I can achieve this with using Views?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting $output = array(); to $output = ''; and see if that fixes the issue. Also, I would recommend using views instead of custom SQL query while dealing with Drupal.

- [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)

Comment: No errors now, but it doesn't list the blogs. Probably a reason why I shouldn't use custom SQL queries, right? Still I'm not sure how to achieve this goal with Views.